# He is a wolf during the night and she is a crow during the day

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’d like to find the title of a movie I saw when I was younger. **I remember watching it in the 90’s but it could be older**.

It’s kind of a love story, I guess, between a man and a woman, but a priest is jealous so he curses them. **They can never be together because during the night he turns into a wolf and during the day she turns into a crow.** Now, I’m not sure, so maybe the woman is the one who turns into a wolf and the man is the one who turns into a crow, and maybe she turns during the night and he turns during the day, but you get the idea.

I remember that in the end there is an eclipse, allowing them both to be human at the same time, so they kiss and somehow the curse is broken.

Comment: Crows != Hawks, blasphemy!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is almost certainly the 1985 classic [Ladyhawke](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089457/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). I'm guessing you're remembering the "crow" part wrong, since everything else matches perfectly.

From Wikipedia's Plot summary (emphases mine)

> In his insane jealousy the Bishop made a demonic pact to ensure they would be "Always together; eternally apart": **by day Isabeau becomes a hawk, by night Navarre becomes a wolf.** Neither has any memory of their half-life in animal form; only at dusk and dawn of each day can they see each other in human form for one fleeting moment, but can never touch.
>
> [...] Imperius has discovered a way to break the curse; in three days, **a solar eclipse** will create "a day without a night and a night without a day": when the lovers stand together in human form before the Bishop, **the curse will be broken.**

Comment: Meh.  Beat me by 3 seconds.  +1 for faster typing :)

Comment: OOHHHHH! you get it for the faster speed! If only I hadn't lingered picking the DVD sleeve! ha ha

Comment: This is what practicing speed-typing all these years was for. :)

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Both you guys deserve an upvote :)

Comment: A wonderful movie. Now, if only something could be done about that soundtrack.

Comment: Michelle Pfeiffer gave me a Pavlov response to crows in that movie which is confusing for a young lad.

Comment: @dmckee: Any mention of this film should include a prominent *warning* about the soundtrack. I'm just glad I saw it at an age when my musical taste hadn't developed far enough to force me to stop watching.

Comment: Hawks and wolves mate for life. The bishop didn't even give us that

Answer (score 26):

This is likely to be the Cult Classic [Ladyhawke](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089457/), unless there is a very good copyright-infringing duplicate out there!

[image]

From the IMDB page:

> Philipe Gastone, a thief, escapes from the dungeon at Aquila, sparking a manhunt. He is nearly captured when Captain Navarre befriends him. Navarre has been hunted by the Bishop's men for two years, ever since he escaped with the Lady Isabeau who the Bishop has lusted after. Navarre and Isabeau have a curse that the Bishop has placed on them that causes Navarre to be a wolf during the night and Isabeau to be a hawk during the day. Navarre insists that Philipe help him re-enter the city to help him kill the heavily guarded Bishop.

Best thing Matthew Broderick has ever done...*Ferris Bueller* included.

Good Movie!

Comment: Really, better than [sitting in the hay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEtQhqyeIYE)?